# How can I Remove a certain character from multiple filenames in windows 8?

Tags: windows-8, rename, filenames

I have more than thousand of files(type:image). In which some of the filenames contains '+'.
I want to remove '+' from the filename. How can I do it?

Filenames for example:

```
!Bzk76jgCWk~$(KGrHqMOKn!Ew9)B+CdZBMWq4neeCw~~_12
!B8974bQEGk~$(KGrHqQOKkIEzJYk9)nuBM4cmDS1+w~~_12
$(KGrHqZ,!jQE6F7l+FWqBOldOfQg!!~~60_57 (1)
$(KGrHqR,!oIE-uf2+zQdBPsor,!hKw~~60_57
!CD,Prv!!2k~$(KGrHqN,!lMEz+6WFj36BNOdz)CHSQ~~_12
```

Please suggest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multi-rename tools available that can do that, I sometimes use FreeCommander myself. This particular task could also be done using a batch file: Paste the following code in a file with extension *.bat*, in the same folder and execute.

```
@echo off

for %%f in (*.*) do (
    set "x=%%f"
    setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
    set y=!x:+=!
    if not "!x!"=="!y!" rename "!x!" "!y!"
    endlocal
)
```